# How to remove an iPhone from the device list in Console.app

Tags: macos, console

Today I opened Console.app and I found that my Mac can read logs from an iPhone which I connected to build an app quite a long time ago. The problem is that I now cannot find a way to remove this iPhone from this list.

[image: Device list in Console.app]

I checked Window -> Devices & Simulators in XCode, it is not there. I also checked in iTunes, found nothing

I have no clue how to get completely disconnected from this iPhone. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to "untrust" the Mac from the iPhone.

On the iPhone go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy
On the Mac, restart the Console